# Unexpected behaviour of hasOwnProperty

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, if-statement, hasownproperty

I'm writing a function which checks if an object contains keys like 'id' or 'serif:id'. Unfortunately this doesn't work properly.

```js
function returnIdPreferSerifId(object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty('serif:id' === true)) {
        return object['serif:id'];
    } else if (object.hasOwnProperty('id' === true)) {
        return object.id;
    } else {
        console.log(object)
        console.log(object.hasOwnProperty('serif:id' === true))
        console.log(object.hasOwnProperty('id' === true))
        throw `ID not found in Layer 1!`;
    }
}
```

The test object is:

```
{ 
  id: 'ska',
  d: 'M255.848,145.321l19.839,0.054l12.677,8.62l6.085,-8.62l-8.62,-29.41l-30.488,13.637l0.507,15.719Z',
  style: 'fill:rgb(187,222,251);stroke:white;stroke-width:1.33px;' 
}
```

I expect the function to return 'ska' as it is the objects id.
Instead the console shows

```sh
false
false

path\to\module\modules\svgHandler.js:135
        throw `ID not found in Layer 1!`;
        ^
ID not found in Layer 1!
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: You've written the expressions incorrectly.  Also, explicit comparisons to `true` or `false` are usually unnecessary. If a function returns a boolean, just use it directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got your parentheses in the wrong place:

```
if (object.hasOwnProperty('serif:id' === true))
```

should be

```
if (object.hasOwnProperty('serif:id') === true)
```

and you could drop the === true if you like

```
if (object.hasOwnProperty('serif:id'))
```

Answer (score 1):

`object.hasOwnProperty('serif:id' === true)` will evaluate like below.

```
object.hasOwnProperty(false)
false //if false is not key of object.
```

You should move `=== false` outside the `()`

```
if (object.hasOwnProperty('serif:id') === true)
```

Or you don't need to compare something with `true` in if statement.

```
if (object.hasOwnProperty('serif:id'))
```